# Localhost blocks when inserting to DB (the data is inserted but the server doesn't response)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

the code below extract data from a csv file and insert it in DB. the csv file have 3 columns : title; year; author
The thing is, i don't want to insert the name of the author but his id (check the code to see what i did).
i get the result i want in DB but the server blocks after that.
How can i improve the code so the server will not block.

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'database';


    $x = 0; // Number of lines added to DB

    $isOK = FALSE;
    $output = '';

    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$db.';host='.$host;

    $fh = fopen ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
    fgetcsv($fh); //to escape the first line in the csv file

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
        //for table books :
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `books`(`title`, `year`, `author_id`) ';
        $sql .= 'VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        //for table authors :
        $sql2 = 'SELECT `author_id` FROM `authors` WHERE `name` = :name';
        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $books = fgetcsv($fh, 300, ';');
            //to get author_id knowing his name **********
            $stmt2->execute(array(':name'=>$books[2]));
            $row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $books[2] = $row['author_id'];
            //********************************************
            if (isset($books) && is_array($books) && count($books)>0) {
                $result = $stmt->execute($books);
                $isOK = $result ? TRUE : FALSE;
                if(!($isOK)) {
                    $pdo = NULL;
                    fclose($fh);
                    header('Location: ../error.php');
                }else {
                    $x++;
                    $output .= '<br />INSERTED: ' . $result . ':' . vsprintf('%s | %s | %s ', $books) . PHP_EOL;
                }
            } else {
                $output .= '<br />FAILED  : ' . var_export($result, TRUE);
            }
        }
        $pdo = NULL;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p><span style="color:red;">Une erreur s\'est produite :</span> '.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$e->getTraceAsString().'</p>';
    }
    fclose($fh);

} else {
    header('Location: import_books_from_csv.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Try changing error mode in PDO to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and see what happens. Also add `echo $output;` after `fclose()`.

Comment: I don't know how but when i changed the error mode it worked. The server work fine now. Thx a lot :D